# Performance Query

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I would like to know the maximum data ingress/egress(packet per sec) limit in orion broker for both northbound and southbound.

suppose orion broker is integrated with json IoT agent. now what would be the data ingress/egress limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hard limit for that. Performance depends on package size, network, number of nodes, CPU, RAM, number -and behavior- of active subscriptions... if there are IotAgents involved (MQTT? HTTP?), balancing/failover policies, MongoDB environment... and so on...

So for any kind of performance question, at any system, it is a must to specify infrastructure, architecture, deployment and use case scenario. In other case the question can't be answered.

Best way to know it is to make a test with your concrete scenario, within the given environment. There are some public performance docs (made by the Fiware Foundation)but they are not extrapolable to any kind of environment.

Best.

Comment: [Link](https://github.com/FIWARE/load-tests/tree/6ada01fb932e21208de69534e7253841402f1f9f/testReports/orion) to the tests that @Perrolobo mention in the answer